# How to extract a set of numbers from a cell and add them up in Google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, numbers, google-sheets-formula

I have an input cell which contains a list of expenses/prices in a string form and would like to **extract all numbers and add them up in an output cell**.
From the list of items below for example, I would like to see on the adjacent right cell the total of £290.89.

How do I achieve this on Google sheets?

[image]

Comment: Can we assume that all the prices have either a pound sign or decimal places or both? Otherwise, there would be no way of telling them from the quantities like 4 and 10 in your example.

Comment: Yes we can assume that all prices will definitely have the pound sign and may have decimal places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(K1,"(.*£|.*- )","@"),"@"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think this might work if that is an image of cell B2.

```
=SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2,CHAR(10))),"- ",0),,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one, which assumes that prices have a pound sign or a decimal place:

```
=sum(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,"\s\d+\s"," "),"[^\d\.]"," ")," "))
```

[image]